# $X,Y$ are compact Hausdorff. $f$ is bijective continuous. Is $f$ a homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness

> Let $X,Y$ be compact Hausdorff spaces. Let $f:X\to Y$ be one-to-one, onto and continuous. Show that $f$ is a homeomorphism.

I came up with this "proof" but I am very sure it is wrong. In order to show that $f$ is a homeomorphism, we only need to show that $f^{-1}$ is continuous. So I considered an open set $U\subset X$, and wanted to show that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $Y$. Suppose that's not the case, then $f^{-1}(U)$ is closed in $Y$. Then its preimage $f^{-1}f^{-1}(U)$ is closed in $X$ since $f$ is continuous. Then that implies that $U$ is closed in $X$, a contradiction.

I feel like I messed up with the last part. Also, how do I use "compact" and "Hausdorff" here? I know that a compact set in a Hausdorff space has to be closed.

Comment: Your notation is off. You want to show the inverse map $f^{-1}$ is continuous, and this means you have to show that $(f^{-1})^{-1}(U)$ is open in $Y$ for any open $U \subset X$. Equivalently (and in fact more useful in this problem), you can replace the words "open" in the above sentence with closed and follow the guidance of the answer given below.

Comment: @NoahOlander Ohohoh now I see it

Comment: See also: [Continuous bijection between compact and Hausdorff spaces is a homeomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3042668)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, let's consider an open $K \subset X$, then its complement is closed. Closed subspace of a compact space is also compact. Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ - continous map. Then, since the image of a compact set is compact (the map is continous), $Y - f(K)$ is compact. Since the compact subspace of a Hausdorff space is closed, $Y - f(K)$ is closed and then $f(K)$ is open.

So, $f$ maps open spaces to open spaces and this also is true for $f^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

The proof is wrong because if a set is not open that doesn't mean it is closed.  A set may be neither open nor closed.  Instead work with the complement of $U$, that is closed.

The point is that a closed subset of a compact set is compact and a compact subset of a hausdorff space is closed.  So show that $f(\text{closed})=\text{closed}$ and that will show $f^{-1}$ is continuous.