# Proving $[0,2]\big/[1,2]$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

> Prove $[0,2]\big/[1,2]$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$.

Where $A\big/B$ is the quotient set where all points of $B$ are identified as a single point (and other remain distinct). Our definition of a homeomorphism $i:X\to Y$ amounts to a bijective map between topological spaces such that the topology of $X$ is exactly

$$\left\{ i^{-1}(U):U\text{ open in }Y \right\}$$

and we have no other theorems to hasten the process. My problem is mostly with formality, where a lot of structure is apparently "lost" when moving to talk about representatives instead, and the discussion becomes problematic. My proof follows, but it feels like I'm doing something wrong for a relatively simple quotient:

Define $f:\left[0,2\right]\big/\left[1,2\right]\to\left[0,1\right]$ by

$$ f\left(\left[x\right]\right)=\begin{cases}
x & x\in\left[0,1\right)\\
1 & x\in\left[1,2\right]
\end{cases}$$

to see this is well defined, if $\left[x\right]=\left[y\right]$ there are two cases, either $x,y\in\left[0,1\right)$ and then $x=y$, or $x,y\in\left[1,2\right]$ and are both mapped to $1$. Then f is injective, as $\left[x\right]\neq\left[y\right]$ means $x\neq y$ hence if $\left[x\right],\left[y\right]\neq\left[1\right]$,
$$f\left(\left[x\right]\right)=x\neq y=f\left(\left[y\right]\right)$$
and if without loss of generality $\left[x\right]=\left[1\right]$, then $\left[y\right]\neq\left[1\right]$ and

$$f\left(\left[y\right]\right)=y\neq1\neq f\left(\left[x\right]\right).$$

It is surjective as for any $x\in\left[0,1\right], f\left(\left[x\right]\right)=x$.

Suppose $q:\left[0,2\right]\to\left[0,2\right]\big/\left[1,2\right]$ is the quotient map, then given an open interval (subbasis element) $\left(a,b\right)\subset\left[0,1\right]$, if $b\leq1$ then
$$q^{-1}\left(f^{-1}\left(\left(a,b\right)\right)\right)=\left(a,b\right)$$

and if $b>1$,

$$q^{-1}\left(f^{-1}\left(\left(a,b\right)\right)\right)=\left(a,2\right] $$

showing that $f\circ q:\left[0,2\right]\to\left[0,1\right]$ is continuous, and therefore so is f. Similarly if $U\subset\left[0,2\right]\big/\left[1,2\right]$ is open, if $\left[1\right]\notin U$ then

$$f\left(U\right)=q^{-1}\left(U\right)=\left\{ x:\left[x\right]\in U\right\}$$

thus from the continuity of $q$, $f\left(U\right)$ is open, and if $\left[1\right]\in U$,

$$f\left(U\right)=q^{-1}\left(U\setminus\left[1\right]\right)\cup\left\{ 1\right\}$$

where $q^{-1}\left(U\setminus\left[1\right]\right)$ is open, as given any point $x$ it satisfies $x<1$, and given an open neighborhood $U_{x}$ of $\left[x\right]$ in U, if it contains $\left[1\right]$, then

$$q^{-1}\left(U_{x}\setminus\left[1\right]\right)=q^{-1}\left(U_{x}\right)\setminus\left[1,2\right]$$

which is open, showing $U\setminus\left[1\right]$ also contains such a neighborhood. We therefore only need to find a neighborhood for $1\in\left[0,1\right]$, but since $U$ contains a neighborhood for $\left[1\right]$, $q^{-1}\left(U\right)$ contains a neighborhood for $\left[1,2\right]$, which must contain an interval of the form $\left(a,2\right]$ for $a<1$, hence $\left(a,1\right]\in f\left(U\right)$ showing that $f\left(U\right)$ is indeed open and $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: What is your exact question ?

Comment: @elidiot To verify the proof.

Comment: @elidiot yeah, exactly what YuiTo Cheng said. Forgot the verification tag exists. I'm also interested to know if there are simpler ways of proving it without extra theorems though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simplier argument using a classical lemma.

You have shown that $f$ is a continuous bijection. Then, we now that $[0,2]/[1,2]$ is compact, as it is a quotient of a compact space. Also, $[0,1]$ is Hausdorff, so any continuous bijection $[0,2]/[1,2]\to[0,1]$ is a homeomorphism.

You can find [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3042668/continuous-bijection-between-compact-and-hausdorff-spaces-is-a-homeomorphism) a proof of the lemma (it is easy).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> $f\left(\left[y\right]\right)=y\neq1\neq f\left(\left[x\right]\right)$

I guess you meant $f\left(\left[y\right]\right)=y\neq1=f\left(\left[x\right]\right)$.

> if $b\leq1$ then $\ldots$ and if $b>1$ $\ldots$

It is  $b<1$ and $b\geq1$ respectively.

> $f\circ q$ is continuous, and therefore so is $f$

I don't remember this fact, but that is probably my memory's fault.

> hence $(a,1]\in f(U)$

You mean $(a,1]\subseteq f(U)$.

With the corrections, your proof is correct from my point of view. And the "errors" you made could just be typos for all I know.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is very helpful. First and fourth are definitely typos, and for the third we have shown that $q$ being a quotient map means $f$ is continuous if and only if $f\circ q$ is continuous. About the second I'm still not sure, since if $b=1$ then $1$ is still not in the open interval.

Answer (score 1):

It's clear that $g: [0,2] \to [0,1]$ defined by

$$g=
\begin{cases}
x & \text{ if } x \le 1\\
1 & \text{ if } x \ge 1\\
\end{cases}
$$

is continuous by an application of the pasting lemma for the two closed sets $[0,1]$ and $[1,2]$ and $g$ restricted to the first is the identity and to the second the constant map $1$. So both are continuous on a closed part, they agree on the intersection $\{1\}$ and so the total function is continuous.

Your $f: [0,2]/{[1,2]} \to [0,1]$ is indeed well-defined and it obeys the property that $f \circ q=g$ (both sides are maps from $[0,2]$ to $[0,1]$) and this already shows $f$ is continuous. ($O$ open in $[0,1]$ implies that $g^{-1}[O]$ is open in $[0,2]$ and this equals $q^{-1}[f^{-1}[O]]$ and as $q^{-1}[f^{-1}[O]]$ is open, so is $f^{-1}[O]$ by the definition of the quotient topology).

So $f$ is continuous and bijective. The openness of $f$ needs a bit more work along the lines of what you did, distinguishing the case where $[1]$ is in the open set or not. There might be a smoother argument, perhaps.