# Topology Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $X$ be Hausdorff space and $f$ is a continuous function from $[0,1]$ to $X$. If $f$ is one-one, then image of $f$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1].$

I did something like defining mapping $g$ from image of $f$ to $[0,1]$  as $g(x)=y$ where $f(y)=x.$ Everything is going fine except $g$ is continuous means I don't know how to show continuity of $g$. Any hint please. 
Thank you.

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3042668/continuous-bijection-between-compact-and-hausdorff-spaces-is-a-homeomorphism

Answer (score 1):

To show that $g$ is continuous, you have to show that the preimage of a closed set under $g$ is closed. By definition of $g$ this is equivalent to the fact that $f$ maps closed sets to closed sets.

Now assume that $M \subset [0,1]$ is closed. Then it is compact and by continuity of $f$ you get that $f(M)$ is also compact. Now $X$ is a Hausdorff-space which means that compact subsets of $X$ are closed and therefore $f(M)$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Lemma: The continuous image of a compact space is compact.

Little Lemma: A compact subset of a Hausdorff space is a closed set.

Littler Lemma: A subspace $Z$ of a Hausdorff space $X$ is also a Hausdorff space.

Littlest Lemma: If $f:Y\to X$ is continuous and $f(Y)$ has the subspace toology as a subspace of $X$ then $f:Y\to f(Y)$ is continuous.

Theorem: If $Y,Z$ are compact Hausdorff spaces and $f:Y\to Z$ is a continuous bijection then $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Apply  to $Y=[0,1]$ and $Z=f(Y)\subset X,$ noting that $[0,1]$ is compact Hausdorff.

Comment: If you need more details or proofs, please ask.

Comment: Thanks. I have one doubt in my question what if $f$ is not one one, still image of $f$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]?$

Comment: If $f$ is not one-to-one then $f([0,1])$ could contain just one point, or it could  be a circle or ......