# Example of Jordan path

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

I need to construct an example of Jordan path in $\mathbb{C}$ for which it’s support has positive plane Lebesgue measure. And how to prove proof that for closed Jordan path it’s support is homeomorphic to circle (intuitively it’s clear but I want more precise proof)

Comment: You can close [this curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osgood_curve) and the homeomorphism is because you have a [continuous bijection between compact Hausdorff](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3042668/736212).

Comment: I need a curve with positive one-dimensional Lebesgue measure. I think this example is complicated

Comment: You said 'plane Lebesgue measure'. Just the circle has positive length.

Comment: It is needed to be support of positive measure

Comment: I don't know what are saying. The interesting question that sounds like what you are asking is answered by the link above. If not, clarify what you call support and clarify which measure you want.