# Are continuous bijections between compact and topological spaces homeomorphisms?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

We know that [continuous bijections between compact and Hausdorff spaces are homeomorphisms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3042668/continuous-bijection-between-compact-and-hausdorff-spaces-is-a-homeomorphism?noredirect=1&lq=1). I.e. if $(X,\tau_{X})$ is a compact topological space, $(Y,\tau_{Y})$ is a Hausdorff space and $f:(X,\tau_{X})\rightarrow(Y,\tau_{Y})$ is a continuous bijective function, then $f$ is a homeomorphism.

However, does this hold if we relax the assumption that $(Y,\tau_{Y})$ is a Hausdorff space, i.e. only a topological space? If not, provide a counterexample.

Comment: Can you find an example of a closed subset of a compact space that is not compact?

Comment: Hint: consider finite spaces.

Comment: Or a compact subset of a compact space that is not closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $X$ to be a finite set ($|X|>1$) with discrete topology and $X'$ be the same set with indiscrete topology.

Consider $i : X \to X'$, the identity function.

Clearly, $X$ is compact (as it is finite). $i$ is clearly bijective and continuous (you cannot demand more open sets in the left space).

But, obviously, this is not a homeomorphism.

Comment: Similarly, take any compact space $X$ that is NOT indiscrete, and do the same thing.

Comment: @JustinYoung Yeah, this is just a very easy example.